# what is the difference between '&:hover' and '& :hover' psuedo selectors

Tags: css, sass, material-ui

I'm styling a Button in Material-UI and I notice a strange behavior when I try to add style to the hover effect (strange because it was unexpected and I don't understand the difference). Initially I tried `& :hover` and only the inner span of the button was affected. I then tried `&:hover` and I got the desired style. Whats the difference between the two? Other than the space of course ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `&:hover` effect directly to the element that you are selected
- `& :hover` effect to elements that are inside your selected element.

From [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

- `.class1.class2`  Selects all elements with both - name1 and name2 set within its class attribute
- `.class1 .class2` Selects all elements with name2 that is a descendant of an element with name1